# Custom StyleCop rule to check XML documentation syntax

Tags: c#, code-analysis, stylecop, xml-documentation, static-code-analysis

I recently started to use StyleCop for my C# code static analysis. So far, I'm very satisfied with the results, but I encountered a few rules, that I need to change just a little to suit my needs better, so I decided to code custom StyleCop rules using code snippets like:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010822/how-to-combine-multiple-custom-stylecop-rules-under-a-single-custom-rules-node)

The rules I need to change are specificly SA1623 and SA1642. These rules both check constructors and properties XML documentation and validate only if the summary tags of these objects start with specificly defined strings ("Initialises a new instance of..." for constructors and "gets or sets..." for properties). I want to keep this functionality, but I want to change the strings that the rules validate.

So in the end, I would disable rules SA1623 and 1642 and instead enable my new custom rules my1623 and my1642 in StyleCop.

Here is my problem: When I call the WalkDocument() function in the AnalyzeDocument(CodeDocument) function, I add callback functions as parameters to it. These functions have my custom rules defined. However, in the code snippets I've seen, parameters of these callback functions vary both in datatype and count. I found no clue as what parameters and what type I should implement my callbacks with in order to check the contents of constructors or properties XML documentation summary tags.

```
public override void AnalyzeDocument(CodeDocument document)
{
    CsDocument doc = document as CsDocument;
    if (doc.RootElement == null || doc.RootElement.Generated)
        return;

    doc.WalkDocument(custom_SA1642, custom_SA1623);
}

private bool custom_SA1642(/*params?*/)
{
    /* Check the content of <summary> tags of XML documentation of constructors */
}

private bool custom_SA1623(/*params?*/)
{
    /* Check the content of <summary> tags of XML documentation of properties */

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could check the source code of some StyleCop plugins which can already do it.
The one I am aware of is StyleCop+. It's source code on the GitHub and it can override SA1642 with own custom rule.
It doesn't allow to configure the string for SA1642, but can configure other things - so you could see how all it is done in terms of C# code as well.